# How to flash TAB 900 Android Tablet

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rom-flashing, installation

I have Sunstech TAB 900 tablet, and it ships with Android 4.0. I want to install Android Lollipop on it.

I have tried to use `"apply update from external storage"`, but it gives me `"E: Short write of /tmp/sideload/package.zip (No space left on device)"` error, even if I have 1GB available. and Lollipop needs only 800MB.

I also tried to install CWM, but the device is not supported, also tried the fastboot method but again it can't detect my device, and there is no drivers provided by the company, but `adb` detects it.

So, is there any way to install Lollipop, or it's a dead end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be a custom recovery for your device first that will allow you to do a backup of your current stock ROM. Second Lollipop has to be released for your tablet. There could be a custom recovery for the Sunstech TAB 900 from TWRP. Look into it. Go to the Play Store or do a search for custom recovs for your device.

Comment: I see, so it can't run on all devices! Thanks for the informations man!